# Evaluate the sum by writing it as a definite integral

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, summation, solution-verification

I am asked to evaluate the following sum by writing it as a definite integral. I was hoping if my methods we correct for the following sums.

> $\displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{3}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{2+\frac{3i}{n}}{\sqrt{1+\frac{3i}{n}}}}$

We know $\Delta x=\frac{3}{n}$. We know know that $x_i^*=a+i\Delta x.$ Is $a$ starting at $0$ or $1$? I am tempted to say it's starting at $1$ but I am not sure how to justify this. How would I turn this into an integral after?

My second sum is the following:

> $\displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+i^2}}}$

I could rewrite the sum as follows, which gives:

$\displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{i^2}{n^2}}}}$

$\displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)^2}}}$

Here $\Delta x=\frac{1}{n}$. I am pretty sure here, $a$ starts from $0$ since $x_i^*=a+i\Delta x.$ If we only have $\frac{1}{n}$ then no terms were added to $x_i^*$ so this means $a$ starts at $0$. Of course, this means $b=1$.

So as an integral, I can write this as $\displaystyle{\int_{0}^{1}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}dx=\sinh^{-1}(x)|_{0}^{1}=\sinh^{-1}(1)$

Is this correct? It would be great if someone could guide me in the first question and verify my 2nd sum.

Comment: you havedone the second sum right except for a few typo's in your steps.Here is a general trick.Replace the sum  by integral,$\frac{1}{n}$ by dx and  wherever $\frac{i}{n}$ by x

Comment: I didn't even see that. Thank you! What about the bounds for the 1st and second sum? How would I go about deciding that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The first sum**

Whether the integral starts at $0$ or $1$ actually depends on you. Here's what I mean:

$$\displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{3}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{2+\frac{3i}{n}}{\sqrt{1+\frac{3i}{n}}}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{3}n\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1+\left(1+\frac{3i}n\right)}{\sqrt{1+\frac{3i}n}}=\int_1^4\frac{1+x}{\sqrt x}\,dx$$

but you can also write $$\displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{3}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{2+\frac{3i}{n}}{\sqrt{1+\frac{3i}{n}}}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{3}n\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{2+\left(\frac{3i}n\right)}{\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{3i}n\right)}}=\int_0^3 \frac{2+x}{\sqrt{1+x}}\,dx$$

You can see that it's just about shifting, and it's arbitrary. For the sake of easier computing, I will pick the first one.

**The second sum**

There is a typo in your post. It should be $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+i^2}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\color{red}{\frac{1}{n}}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{i}n\right)^2}}$$

and the rest of your work seems fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

Your second sum is evaluated correctly.

General trick is to replace the sum by an integral,$\frac{1}{n}$ by $dx$ and $\frac{i}{n}$ by $x$.

About the bounds suppose we calculate $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n} \sum_{f(n)}^{g(n)} f(i/n)$$
The lower bound of integral is taken $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{n}$$
and upper bound replace $f(n)$ by $g(n)$